# speed of light measurement

Tags: optics

u can video call one smartphone from another via wireless internet connection, ie: the signal travels from one device to a satellite and then to the other device. but i want to avoid network noise and fluctuations, could i do the same thing but using a stable way, like exclusively wired connection (the equivalent for the signal to travel to the "satellite" via wire (optical fibers) and via wire again to the second device. The 2 devices may be in the same place, one next to the other. Thanks in advance

Comment: Ahh.  What's all that got to do with measuring the speed of light?

Comment: Smartphones don’t communicate with a satellite.

Comment: you can use POTS for wired use but not measure speed of light as group delays exist in passive filters and buffers

Comment: We already know the speed of light. Why do you want to prove it again? Also, this question has a lot of false information. Your second to last sentence has quotations around the word, "satellite". Are you being euphemistic?

Comment: I think the answer is "no".  There are too many unknowns using wireless or wired internet.  And I have never seen a smart phone with an optical fiber connector.

Comment: my dear fellows, what i want to do, not for my pleasurebut because i was asked to, is to use the droste effect to measure the speed of light. if i want to measure it in order of magnitude i need distance and corresponding time combination (using the droste effect also appears the number of recursively nested images) such that i get d/t~10^8m/s. the problem is, if u do the algebra, given that a commercial device screen refresh rate is~1/60s, the resolution of the screen also enables ~50 images to be counted, from distance~1m, which means total_t=constant(N*processing time)+N*d/c, PROBLEM, HELP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It deosn't go to a satellite. they delay is just internet and codec latency. especially if the call is going through a server in some inconvenient location.

you can have reduced latency by using a sever that's more conveniently located.

but using the droste effect will ge you the latency, however a large part of that time is not travel time of the signal, and most signals do not travel at lightspeed anyway.  you can perhaps get a lower bound on the speed of light. `

Comment: for example on the moon?

Comment: for eample in your basement.

Comment: definately can't use the moon. it's a satellite.

Comment: what i want to do, not for my pleasure but because i was asked to, is to use the droste effect to measure the speed of light. if i want to measure it in order of magnitude i need distance and corresponding time combination (using the droste effect also appears the number of recursively nested images, N) such that i get d/t~10^8m/s. the problem is, if u do the algebra, given that a commercial device screen refresh rate is~1/60s and the resolution of the screen also enables ~50 images to be counted, from distance~1m, which means total_t=constant(N*processing time)+N*d/c, PROBLEM, HELP!

Comment: In the example of my basement, as u say,what should be the total path-distance of the signal (from device No1 to reach device No2)?

Comment: you can't measure the speed of light in this way,